# Two Software Updater in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, update-manager

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04. But I am able to see two 'Software Updater'.

May i know why there are two Software Updater ? How to remove duplicate one ?

[image]

Comment: I guess you are referring to software updater and software & updates. A picture will help us better.

Comment: If that is not the case, there may be duplicate entries can arise from multiple `.desktop `files in `/usr/share/applications/`, previously a bug is reported here  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1562409. Go through all the comments before deleting any `.desktop` files

Comment: As I said earlier, those two apps are completely different.

Comment: Software Updater looks for and updates apps on your system.  Software & Updates is how you control where the updates / apps come from.  Software & Updates is also where the Additional Drivers tab is found for video and sometimes audio.  They are two different apps.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between Software Updater and Ubuntu Software Updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789668/what-is-the-difference-between-software-updater-and-ubuntu-software-updates)

Comment: I updated to 20.04 from 18.04 just a few days ago and I noticed this too.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Software Updater and Software & Updates are two separate apps even though their icons are similar in Ubuntu 20.04.